# Получение N-го элемента в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть `ArrayList`, который заполняется данными из бд. Запись элементов в строке `ArrayList.get(0)` выглядит так: [`1114`, `Adres`, `Name`, `FirstName`, `123`, `0`, `1`].

Как мне получить, например поле `Name`?

Comment: Объект какого типа вы сохраняете в ArrayList?

Comment: Сюда по вопросу  ArrayList заполнен объектами String. Вам необходимо реализовать класс для хранения данных  [1114, Adres, Name, FirstName, 123, 0, 1]. И для каждого свойства геттеры и сеттеры. Иначе парсить String. А какого вида будет строка, если какое-то поле не заполнено (в случае, если оставить String)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При работе с обобщенными коллекциями необходимо указывать конкретный тип, с которыми они будут работать. Т.к. запись в элементе у вас выглядит так:

> [1114, Adres, Name, FirstName, 123, 0, 1]

то необходимо создать примерно такой объект:

```
public class DatabaseObject {

    public long id;
    public String address;
    public String name;
    public String firstName;
    public int someDigit;
    public int yetSomeDigit;
    public int yetSomeSomeDigit;

}
```

и заполнять его данными из бд, после чего добавлять его в `ArrayList`
Тогда доступ к имени можно получить так: `myArrayLis.get(0).name`, к другим полям, получить доступ можно аналогичным способом.

P.S: для уменьшения объема кода я не стал использовать геттеры и сеттеры, а объявил поля `public`. Однако в реальном проекте лучше объявить поля класса `private` и для каждого поля реализовать getter/setter.

Answer (score 3):

По-хорошему, вам надо было создать класс, который будет представлять объект, в который вы будете вносить в определенные поля нужные данные. А потом, просто брать `arrayList.get(0).get<Name>();`.

Answer (score 2):

Если в ArrayList вы храните String, то можно преобразовать вашу строку в массив строк, разделив оную по запятой

```
String[] strings=ArrayList.get(0).split(",");
String name=strings[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

`getName()` - это геттер из `Entities`

```
public class Entities{
        private Long id;
        private String address;
        private String name;
        private String lastName;
        private int numberF;
        private int numberS;
        private int numberT;
        //getter and setter
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Entities> list = new ArrayList<Entities>();
        list.get(0).getName();
    }
```